# How to get wxPython 2.9.4 running on Windows XP with Python 3.3.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

Hmm, I'm missing something. I installed wxPython under Python33. When typing 'import wx', I am getting an error message:

ImportError: No module named 'wx'
Someone knows what this is about?

I looked at this Q&A on here: "“import wx fails after installation of wxPython on Windows XP" and "importing the wx module in python" but it's vaguely related to my issue. This one "Python ImportError: No module named wx" seems to have good answers, but I don't know how to add C:\Python33\site-package\wx-2.9.4-msw to my PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Obviously, I am too new for this and asking banal questions. However, I trust someone is willing to provide an answer.

Comment: I don't think wxPython yet supports Python 3. Good luck.

Comment: many packages/libraries do not yet support python 3 ... which is kind of a shame

Comment: Actually, I would say that most actively developed packages now support Python 3 or are working on support for it.

Answer (score 2):

Project Phoenix is in alpha, but IS available for Python 3 right now. You can get a snap shot build here: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ FYI: Project Phoenix only supports the standard widgets with very limited support for the custom modules at the time of this writing.

The standard "classic" build for wxPython 2.9 does NOT currently support Python 3.

For information about setting PYTHONPATH, see the following:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/24/python-101-setting-up-python-on-windows/
- http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html
- [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

wxPython does not support Python 3. You will have to use Python 2.7. 
[Project Phoenix](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix) is aiming to support Python 3, but this is still in development.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. How far are we looking ahead for compatibility and where is/ how to edit this PYTHONPATH? Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer above, Project Phoenix will support Python 3 but it's still in development. PYTHONPATH is a user variable, you either edit it in your Windows environment settings or type `EXPORT PYTHONPATH=/home/easypeezy/pythonpath`.